# Team Foundation Server deleted local files after I undid pending changes

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have a big problem! I made lots of changes to my c# project on my local machine. I added, deleted, modified, etc. It's been about a week since I've checked anything in to TFS so when I did a check-in, TFS threw some errors saying it couldn't find some files (ones that I had deleted, ok that's fine).

So now what I did was really stupid!
I undid all pending changes in TFS for that project and it totally wiped everything on my local machine back to some earlier version that I had checked in last week. All my files that I had worked on this last week were gone! What do I do!? is there any way to get my recent stuff back or am I screwed?

Comment: Hopefully some backups are done on a regular basis on your machine, otherwise i think you might be :(

Comment: why does TFS mess with local files if I'm changing files in the repo? is there a way to turn this off?

Comment: @user1186050 You're not changing files in the repo.  The files don't change in the repo until you check them in.

Comment: This line is confusing: "It's been about a week since I've checked anything in to TFS so when I did a check-in, TFS threw some errors saying it couldn't find some files (ones that I had deleted, ok that's fine)." - did you complete the check-in operation? Or did you undo before you checked-in to TFS? Just checking for that last straw here :)

Comment: I think maybe I undid before the check in completed. I don't actually think it completed because it had the errors! but when I looked in the repo I did see some of the files I checked in, probably just not all of them...

Answer (score 2):

You should be checking in frequently to avoid mistakes like this. If the files are gone from your file system, they're gone. You can see if you can use a file recovery utility to undelete them, but past that, there's no way to get them back.