# Recover files (changes) after "undoing pending changes" in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs

I had about 20 files pending changes in my solution in **Visual Studio 2015**,I had a problem with repository so clicked on "Undo pending changes" thought I had already had shelved my changes. After undoing pending changes I noticed that I hadn't created any shelveset of those change.

I googled a bit about it and I found this link [How can I get my changes back after clicking “Undo pending changes…” in Visual Studio 2013 and TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869918/how-can-i-get-my-changes-back-after-clicking-undo-pending-changes-in-visual)

I tried the solution mentioned in answers of link above but there is no **TFSTemp** folder in my **AppData\Local\Temp** folder do notice that I'm using **Visual Studio 2015** but the user asked this question is using Visual Studio 2013. **Maybe vs 2015 store TFSTemp in different location but where ???**

Any Idea about how I can get my changes back???

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4):

The TFS Temp folder should be the same path "**AppData\Local\Temp\TFSTemp**". It's not related to VS version. If you could not find it in your own account, give a try with Admin account (If the VS run in Admin mode)

[image]
You should be checking in frequently or setup some sort of **backup system** to avoid mistakes like this. If the files are gone from your file system, they're gone.  Maybe a file recovery utility could do the trick, but the solution is too complicated. Besides past that, there's no way to get them back.