# Recover deleted files/codes from visual studio while doing check-in in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, file-recovery

While doing code check-in for 4 files , got conflict for 1 file and i resolved that conflict and did undo pending changes for only that file , but undo changes happened for all the files and what ever new files/codes added are all deleted.
**How to recover those newly added Code ?**

Tried

1. Pressed ctrl+Z in the the pages where code added and restore
   folder to previous version from folder level.
2. Checked in recycle
   bin
3. Even tried by installing .net reflector , but don't know how
   to use that for recovering deleted files/codes .

Comment: code is in c# language .

Comment: No , this question is not regarding to Git , While doing code check-in in TFS , newly added codes have been deleted , i want to recover deleted codes/files .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get my changes back after clicking "Undo pending changes..." in Visual Studio 2013 and TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869918/how-can-i-get-my-changes-back-after-clicking-undo-pending-changes-in-visual)